# Como declarar e inicializar matrizes bidimensionais?

Tags: java, array, matriz, estrutura-de-dados

Eu tenho que guardar a linha, coluna e conteúdo de uma planilha. Para isso criei uma matriz bidimensional. Minha dificuldade é como a inicializo? Acredito que a declaração já não esteja correta pois recebo `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Nessa situação, matriz é a estrutura de dados adequada?

```
if ("Veículo".equals(cell.getStringCellValue())) {
                            String[][] referencia = new String[][];
                            for (int i = cell.getColumnIndex(); i < 4; i++) {
                                referencia[cell.getRow().getRowNum()][cell.getColumnIndex()] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: você precisa especificar o tamanho do array no `new String[][]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para declarar e inicializar o array corretamente você precisa saber quantas linhas e quantas colunas o mesmo terá, e então inicializar o mesmo assim:

```
String[][] referencia = new String[quantidadeLinhas][quantidadecolunas];
```

sendo que

```
String[][] referencia = new String[10][4];
```

resulta em

```
String[][] referencia = {
    {null,null,null,null},
    {null,null,null,null},
    {null,null,null,null},
    {null,null,null,null},
    {null,null,null,null},
    {null,null,null,null},
    {null,null,null,null},
    {null,null,null,null},
    {null,null,null,null},
    {null,null,null,null}
}
```

Comment: Havia me esquecido que não é uma "estrutura dinâmica", obrigada.